Syntax errors with spdlog
To be honest, I have no idea where exactly the problem is. Everything was running smoothly, till once, the builds just kept failing. Giving these same errors over and over again.

Note that common.h is a file in the spdlog library.
I assumed it had to a problem with my code, so I have been going through each line of it for the past 2 hours. I may not be the most understanding in C++, but I'm confident enough in what I've written. And even if I did something wrong, I have no idea which part of the project should I put here.
I obviously tried to remove the package completely, and comment out all the parts of code that works on it, and it worked, just... without the logging functionality.
I know in these cases, I should be opening an issue on GitHub. But the thing is, it was working perfectly fine till now, and I didn't change nor update the version of the library.

Don't post a picture of texts. Go to Build Output and post the build log from there in a code block keeping the output format.

"I [...] tried to remove the package completely, and comment out all the parts of code that works on it, and it worked," -- That puts you most of the way to a [mre]. The next step is to remove (almost) everything that is currently uncommented, then add back one commented-out line (or as few as possible), thus bringing back the errors.

The command used (by your IDE) to compile your file could be helpful. Also the age/version of your compiler. (Among other things which might be relevant, this might reveal the C++ version you are actually compiling for. Checking the C++ version is something of a long shot since enable_if_t has been standard for 10 years, but still...)
